# Fastest way to list all the file names whose content can match with any of multiple strings

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, xargs

I am trying to figure out what's the fastest way to return all the file names whose content matches with any of multiple strings. I am using xargs for doing iterations.

---

```
$ cat ../Identifiers.list | xargs -i grep -l "{}" .
```

This took around 8 minutes to print all the file names. Is there a faster way?

---

**Identifiers.list** - File content below

```
287434
383460
633491
717255
827734
253735
635373
553888
910366
```

**No of files in Directory** - 36000

```
$ ls -l *.xml | wc -l
36000
```

Comment: As Benjamin suggests, `grep -f` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do it the other way around:

```
printf '%s\0' *.xml | xargs -0 grep -lFf ../Identifiers.list
```

This will check each file just once and stop as soon as a match is found. `-F` uses fixed string matching instead of regular expressions, which should speed things up further.

I think your approach implicitly uses `-L 1` (because of `-i`), so for each line of `Identifier.list`, it goes through all files.

Potentially even faster with parallelization, for example with four parallel processes:

```
printf '%s\0' *.xml | xargs -0 -P 4 grep -lFf ../Identifiers.list
```

For even more speedup, if your files are ASCII, you could use `LC_ALL=C`:

```
printf '%s\0' *.xml | LC_ALL=C xargs -0 -P 4 grep -lFf ../Identifiers.list
```

---

Using `xargs` is a good idea, though, even without parallelization: using grep directly, as in

```
grep -lFf ../Identifiers.list *.xml
```

might throw an error because `*.xml` expands to a command line that is too long.

Comment: Would using `find` and its `-exec` variant with `+`  be an improvement? It would pass as many arguments as possible to each invocation of `grep`, reducing the number of invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. will try that and post results here.

Comment: @Benjamin - Thanks to your wisdom. Using 4 parallel processes, it returned the results 3.3x faster.

Comment: I'm just curious - what is the final time? And what is the total data size (like `cat *.xml | wc -c`)?

Comment: @cody `find -exec {} +` should get the same behvaviour as `| xargs` in terms of minimizing the number of calls to `grep`. I usually prefer `find | -exec {} +` over `xargs`, but the one thing `xargs` can do that `find` can't is parallel execution. There's also [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), but I don't know it well.

Comment: @bharath Sorry, rejected your edit by accident, I've amended it now.

Answer (score 0):

put the strings into one regular expression:

`(?:287434|383460|633491|717255|827734|253735|635373|553888|910366)`

and then grep:

`grep -P '(?:287434|383460|633491|717255|827734|253735|635373|553888|910366)' *`